# Measuring a superposition state of identical particles

Tags: quantum-mechanics, measurements, wavefunction-collapse, identical-particles, born-rule

Suppose that the state of a system of two identcial particles (say, two photons) is given by the following:

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{}2}(|\psi_{1}\rangle|\psi_{2}\rangle + |\psi_{2}\rangle|\psi_{1}\rangle) \, ,$$

where $|\psi_{1}\rangle$ and $|\psi_2\rangle$ represent some mutually orthogonal eigenstates of an observable $\hat{O}$.

Now, what happens when you measure the system with respect to $\hat{O}^2$?
What is the precise description of the state after the measurement?

It looks to me that there are three options to choose from:

1. The system collapses to either $|\psi_{1}\rangle|\psi_{2}\rangle$ or $|\psi_{2}\rangle|\psi_{1}\rangle$ according to the Born rule.
2. The system remains in the superposition state, $\frac{1}{\sqrt{}2}(|\psi_{1}\rangle|\psi_{2}\rangle + |\psi_{2}\rangle|\psi_{1}\rangle)$. No collapse occurs despite the measurement, for you cannot tell which state the system collapsed to.
3. The system is in a mixed state; something like $\frac{1}{2}(|\psi_{1}\rangle|\psi_2\rangle\langle\psi_{2}|\langle\psi_1| + |\psi_2\rangle|\psi_1\rangle\langle\psi_1|\langle\psi_2|)$?

I initially thought that (1) was the correct answer before realizing that both $|\psi_{1}\rangle|\psi_{2}\rangle$ and $|\psi_{2}\rangle|\psi_{1}\rangle$ are not symmetric, and therefore cannot be bosonic states. (2) seems to violate the Born rule. So my guess is (3), but I have no confidence in my speculation. So I'm seeking experts' opinions.

Comment: By using the notation $|\psi_1\rangle |\psi_2\rangle$ you are  implying  that the left and right factors  in in $|\psi_1\rangle |\psi_2\rangle=|\psi_1\rangle \otimes |\psi_2\rangle$  are distinguishable. Similarly what you do you mean by  $O^2$?   On the tensor product of the two states you need to distinguish   $O\otimes {\mathbb I}$ from $ {\mathbb I}\otimes O$ and this descends to ambiguity in $O^2$. Do you mean $(O\otimes {\mathbb I}+{\mathbb I}\otimes O)^2$

Comment: Modulo mike stone's question about what $O^2$ means, I think the answer is option 2. Although I wouldn't phrase it as "you can't tell which state the system has collapsed into," I would say "the measurement says that one photon is in state $\psi_1$ and one photon is in state $\psi_2$" and that is **all** you can say (it's not like Nature secretly knows which photon has collapsed into which state).

Comment: Thanks for your comments. And sorry for the confusing notation $O^2$, by which I think I meant $O \otimes I + I \otimes O$, but maybe I was wrong about what I should have meant. What I had in mind was just the 'upgraded version' of O for two identical particles.

Comment: @Andrew I see, but what's wrong with saying that the system is in a mixed state? The thought is that the abiguity involved in the system after the measurement is not quantum in nature, but a classical one in which we simply have no information as to which combination of states the system is in. It is just difficult to see how option 2 is consistent with the born rule.

Comment: **No** (I'm not yelling, just emphasizing a crucial point). The content of identical particles in quantum mechanics is that **the pure quantum mechanical state is totally symmetric (or antisymmetric) under exchange of any two particles.** There are many experimental consequences of this which **cannot** be reproduced by a classical mixed state, such as Bose-Einstein condensation and the Pauli-Exclusion principle. I'll try to write a more detailed answer, but I feel I need to write this now. I can't let you go out in the world thinking that identical particles are "just" a classical effect :)

Comment: Why do you think there is a problem with the Born rule?

Comment: @Andrew Well, if you have a state $C(|X1\rangle + |X2\rangle)$ before the measurement, then the Born rule will say that it will collapse either to $|X1\rangle$ or $|X2\rangle$ with equal probabilities. Option 2 says otherwise. Isn't it a straightforward violation of the rule?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116389/discussion-between-andrew-and-anti-tachyon).